# href not working when used along with jQuery "Responsive Tabs" plugin

Tags: jquery, href

I'm using the jquery plugin `jquery.responsiveTabs.js` on my landing page. The `href` link on my home page should take me to a specific `Div` within the landing page, but it only takes me to the main page and not the specific Div.

My `href` link structure is as such:

```
http://localhost/SpecificFolder/TargetPage.html#TargetDiv
```

This works when I exclude the `jquery.responsiveTabs.js` from my landing page so I know it is the culprit, but since I need this script not sure how to make it work with it.

I read in some replies that commenting out the code that says "event.preventDefault();" will make it work, I found a line that said `e.preventDefault();`in the script and commented it out, but that hasn't worked for me.

I also tried enclosing the div in a separate `<a>` tag with the `href` id in the `<a>` tag `<a id=#TargetDiv><div></div></a>`, as suggested somewhere else, this also hasn't worked for me.

Anyone else faced with a similar problem? Have you figured a workaround this?

Comment: Please upload your code as a snippet or put in on stackblitz, to explore it

Comment: Hi!! Thanks. Would love to share a snippet but not sure how. How do I write multiple html files for demonstrating the href in a snippet? Stackblitz also seems to allow only one html page. Sorry new to this, would appreciate your inputs.